# How to hold the function returning a pointer to a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Below is the sample structure

```
struct tipc_port {
        void *usr_handle;
        spinlock_t *lock;

};
```

Below is the function call which returns a pointer to the above structure

```
struct tipc_port *tipc_get_port(const u32 ref);
```

now I want to store this pointer to struct in some variable and this variable would be passed to some other function.

**how to declare this variable which would hold the pointer to struct returned by the above function.**

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: `struct tipc_port *variable_name;`

Comment: Please read here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C you declare variables as:

```
type varname;
```

or

```
struct struct_name varname;
```

So in your case you need:

```
struct tipc_port * variable;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way for doing that is to declare your own type :

```
typedef struct{
  void *usr_handle;
  spinlock_t *lock;
}tipc_port_t;
```

And then use it as you may use any other common types :

```
tipc_port_t* tipc_get_port(const u32 ref);
```

And on your code :

```
tipc_port_t *yourStructPointer;
u32 yourRef;

yourStructPointer = tipc_get_port(yourRef);
[...]
```

Or :

```
tipc_port_t yourStructPointer;
u32 yourRef;

&yourStructPointer = tipc_get_port(yourRef);
[...]
```